# JS - Get corresponding object value

Tags: javascript, list, object, key

In my javascript I have an object:

```
var spirits = [
  { name: 'Bourbon (80 proof)', ethanol: 40, sugar: 0, acid: 0 },
  ...
  { name: 'Rum (100 proof)', ethanol: 50, sugar: 0, acid: 0 }
]
```

In my html, there's a `<select>` with all values being the string with the name of the drink (i.e. 'Bourbon (80 proof)'). I already have this value stored in a variable.

I want to `log` the corresponding ethanol percentage (40). Is this possible? I thought about looking through the object and getting the key of the drinkname, and logging this like `spirits[key].ethanol`.

Comment: in the select generated, use value the index of of array. And get both values name and ethanol

Comment: You can also add a `data-` attribute for each key in your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **bind** a `change` event handler to your input.

Also, use `find` method in order to search for an object in your array. `find` method accepts a `callback` provided function as parameter.

```js
var spirits = [
  { name: 'Bourbon (80 proof)', ethanol: 40, sugar: 0, acid: 0 },
  { name: 'Rum (100 proof)', ethanol: 50, sugar: 0, acid: 0 }
]
spirits.forEach(function(item){
  $('select').append('<option>'+item.name+'</option>');
});
$('select').change(function(){
  var self=$(this);
  var obj=spirits.find(function(item){
    return item.name==self.val();
  });
  console.log(obj.ethanol);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

**Pure javascript version.**

```js
var spirits = [
  { name: 'Bourbon (80 proof)', ethanol: 40, sugar: 0, acid: 0 },
  { name: 'Rum (100 proof)', ethanol: 50, sugar: 0, acid: 0 }
]
spirits.forEach(function(item){
  var option=document.createElement('option');
  option.text=item.name;
  document.getElementById('select').appendChild(option);
});
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change',function(){
  var value=this.value;
  var obj=spirits.find(function(item){
    return item.name==value;
  });
  console.log(obj.ethanol);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>
```